# Could the Midwestern (Wisconsin) L sound be described as a semivowel/glide?

Tags: english, ipa, semivowels

In Midwestern accents, words like "love" (with the L in word initial) the L sounds close to the /j/ glide, but I wonder if anyone has noticed this or come across it.

Comment: Do you have a sound recording? Could you perhaps be referring to initial [ɫ]?

Comment: @jogloran it sounding like a /j/ would suggest palatalisation to [ʎ] more than velarisation to [ɫ], although this is certainly less common. It could be that Mahesh is used to English with universal velarisation and is hearing the lack of velarisation (in many English dialects word-initial /l/ is light [l]) as palatalisation when, phonetically, there is none

Comment: Relevantly, Indian English (I am making an assumption here based on their name) tends to pronounce /l/ as [ɭ], and iirc many Indian languages pronounce their non-retroflex /l/ as dental rather than alveolar, something that cross-linguistically often comes along with velarisation, which could explain this perception of a light alveolar [l]

Comment: we will definitely need a recording to say with more certainty though (and I wouldn't want to make these comments into an answer without that, as I'm not familiar enough with Midwestern accents to know if pronouncing /l/ as [ʎ] or [j] is a genuine feature here

Comment: Is it appropriate to share a Youtube video? It is not a direct demonstration of the accent, just someone with such an accent.

Comment: linking a youtube video where you hear this feature (ideally with a timestamp) would be appropriate imo